# CSS-Sass : Is there a way to select a group of elements and iterate over it?

Tags: css, sass

I have an HTML-structure similar this one:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="char">A</div>
  <div class="char">B</div>
  <div class="char">C</div>
  <div class="char">D</div>
</div>
```

Now I want to iterate over each element which has the class "char". 
In JavaScript one possible way would be:

```
// ...
// Select elements with Class "char".
var chars = document.querySelectorAll('.char');
// ...    

// After changing the node-list to an array I could ...
for (i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
  // Do something with the element. E.g. apply an transform.
  // ...
```

Is there a way to accomplish these operations "select group of elements", "iterate over group", "process each element" with Sass?

**Update:**

This should make it clear what I like to do. Things similar like this one but with just Sass (instead of JavaScript):

```js
var chars = document.querySelectorAll('.char');
chars = Array.prototype.slice.call(chars);
var i;

for (i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
  chars[i].style['margin-left'] = (i * 10) + 'px';
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="char">A</div>
  <div class="char">B</div>
  <div class="char">C</div>
  <div class="char">D</div>
  <div class="char">E</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. What would be the purpose of this 'iteration'.

Comment: @Paulie_D Applying an operation on each element of a certain group. For example: 'transform: rotate'. I mean: I can do it with JavaScript. But if there is a way using only Sass I would prefer that.

Comment: Yeah but would the number be different for each iteration...if so, then the answer is no. CSS can't count elements. You'd need to know the number in advance and then use that.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks. That was already helpful. Explains a few things I've seen for far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sass allows you to create own simple function
see for example http://hugogiraudel.com/2013/08/08/advanced-sass-list-functions/

Comment: Hi Oskar. Please add example code to your answer. Thanks.